# parsing bext chunks in broadcast wav file

Tags: c#, parsing, audio, metadata, wav

I m trying to find a way to simply extract a path string that should be embedded in the BWF (broadcast wave) files that are exported using Reaper, a DAW.
I have no experience parsing BWF chunks, but from my understanding we are not looking for either the format chunk or the data chunk or the RIFF, but for a specific bext chunk that should contain the string of the path of the reaper project file that generated the file ( audio export).

Is there a c# audio library that can actually do that ? Any help on the subject would be really appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The Audio Tools Library (ATL) library supports BEXT chunks reading and writing : https://github.com/Zeugma440/atldotnet

```
using ATL.AudioData;

// Load audio file information into memory
Track theTrack = new Track(audioFilePath);

// Display BEXT data
string originator = "", engineer = "", scene = "";
if (theTrack.AdditionalFields.ContainsKey("bext.originator")) originator = theTrack.AdditionalFields["bext.originator"];

System.Console.WriteLine("Originator : " + originator);
```

Apparently you need to know the ID of the BEXT field to read (here : originator); there is no data structure to "hide" it.